# Flutter Unexpected Whitespace

Tags: flutter, dart

This is how my app looks like right now:

[image]

The whitespace between `Departments` and the `American Decorative Arts` shouldnt be there. When I scroll it, the whitespace gets scrolled out.

[image]

This is my code:

```dart
Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 15, 0, 0),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text("Departments", style: GoogleFonts.merriweather(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.black)),
                  Scrollbar(
                    child: SizedBox(
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 438,
                      child: Expanded(
                          child: builder()
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
```

(Full code at https://github.com/MakufonSkifto/view_met/blob/master/lib/home.dart)

After cheking Flutter Inspector, I found that there was actually some hidden margin:

[image]

Even after changing the `height` of the sized box, I can't get it to work. This is as close as it can get to `Text()`. There was no margin between `SizedBox()` and `Scrollbar()`.

If the information given is not enough, please write it in the comments. I will try to give as much as information as I can.

Comment: First, remove the default padding on `ListView.builder` and let me know if that helps.

Comment: I fixed it by adding `padding: EdgeInsets.zero,` to `ListView.builder`. Thank you so much @Benjamin !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `EdgeInsets.zero` to remove the default padding of `ListView.builder` which could be causing the issue.